# Is this equacional function surjective?

Tags: functions

Consider the following functional equation f(x + f(y)) = f(x) + y. Is this function surjective?

I tried used x=y=0

So:

f(0+f(0)) = f(0) + 0
f(f(0)) = f(0)

So I called f(0) = a

f(a) = a

Can I do this? and so , this function is constant and surjective?

Answer (score 1):

In order to prove that $f$ is surjective, you have to show that for any $y$ in the codomain, there exists at least one $x$ in the domain such that $f(x)=y$.

When $y=0$, you obtain $f(x+f(0))=f(x)$. Thus, $f$ is a periodic function and $f(0)$ is a period. Taking $x=0$, we have
$$f(f(y))=f(0)+y$$
Thus, $f(f(y))=f(f(y-f(0)))=f(0)+y-f(0)=y$. Therefore, for any $y$, $x=f(y)$ satisfies $f(x)=y$.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful: $a = f(0)$ is a constant in this context. Hence $f(a)=a$ does not mean that $f$ is constant, it just means that $a$ is a *fixed point* of $f$.

Also, a constant function cannot be a surjective function unless the domain is a singleton, because it cannot "hit" other points.

As to your question, we see that $f(0+f(y)) = f(0)+y$.

Hence for any $k \in \mathbb R$, we see that:

$$f(f(k-f(0))) = f(0+f(k-f(0))) = f(0)+k-f(0)=k$$

as $f(k-f(0)) \in \mathbb R$, $f$ is indeed surjective.